# Linear algebra - Change of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I just want to clarify what does it mean that $A$ is the matrix with respect to basis $(v_1, v_2)$? That it satisfies $Tv = Av$?

Answer (score 0):

If $v_1,v_2$ is a basis, then since $T(v_1),T(v_2)$ are vectors, they may be uniquely expressed in terms of that basis. So we have equations $T(v_1)=av_1+bv_2$ and $T(v_2)=cv_1+dv_2.$ Matrix notation is shorthand for saying the same thing. With respect to the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$, the linear operator $T$ is represented by the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So in the present case, what it means that the operator $T$ is represented by the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-2 & 11\\4 &2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ with respect to the basis $\{(3,1),(0,2)\}$ is that

$$T(3,1) = -2(3,1)+4(0,2) = (-6,6)
$$
and
$$T(0,2) = 11(3,1)+2(0,2) = (33,15).
$$

Now to figure out what the matrix is with respect to the basis $w_1=(1,1)$ and $w_2=(-1,1),$ there are a few options. Your photo cuts off the instructions here, but I think you should write these vectors in terms of the $\{v_1,v_2\}$ basis.

Comment: Thanks. The instruction just says that do not directly use the change of basis formula.

Comment: Can you explain how to further go about this question?